# Redirect my domain with respect to the country using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net

I need to redirect my domain with respect to the country using ASP.NET.

On page load need to check which location from the user access the domain. e.g:

- user access the domain from india www.domainname.com/india
- user access the domain from UAE www.domainname.com/uae

Do not use the JavaScript code.

Comment: You may find this link helpful: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15366/Finding-Countries-and-Cities-Using-IP-Address

Comment: You need to get the user's IP address from the request headers and then convet to IP to country/region

Comment: Not working with your given url. See the error response below.      A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or 
established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 2a01:608:ffff:2872::10:80

Comment: This is another free geolocation service that you can use:http://freegeoip.net/